# DateTime Parsing with MagicalRecord & Date Formats

Tags: magicalrecord

My server provides dates as UTC in the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" e.g. midnight of November 15 for MST is "2013-11-15T07:00:00Z".  This format is the documented default for MagicalRecord but my imported NSManagedObjects are getting ANOTHER 7 hours added to them (NSLog shows "2013-11-15 14:00:00 +0000"), which I can only assume is MR's assumption that the timezone was actually a local one and then offset it to my device's local date to UTC during the import.  How can I stop this?  Is my server not returning the date in the proper format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/484

MagicalRecord have a bug with Z handling, but it seems that pull request for with bug is approved.